# Can Anyone Explain this code piece by piece?

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

**Function that creates a DataFrame with a column for Cluster Number**

````py
def pd_centers(featuresUsed, centers):
    colNames = list(featuresUsed)
    colNames.append('prediction')

    # Zip with a column called 'prediction' (index)
    Z = [np.append(A, index) for index, A in enumerate(centers)]

    # Convert to pandas data frame for plotting
    P = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=colNames)
    P['prediction'] = P['prediction'].astype(int)
    return P
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def pd_centers(**featuresUsed**, centers):
```

inputs of the function are **featuresUsed** that are the features(column names) you already have and centers.

```py
colNames = list(**featuresUsed**)
```

names of columns (**featuresUsed**) are saved here as a list named colNames

```py
colNames.append('prediction')
```

Here a new column name rather than those already existing is added to column names (features) named **prediction**

```py
# Zip with a column called 'prediction' (index)
Z = [np.append(A, index) for index, A in enumerate(centers)]
```

A list of elements of **centers** with their indices are saved as Z
For instance, if we have centers equal to ['CA', 'TEX', 'FLO', 'ORE']
 then Z would become and finally these indices would become the values of prediction column.

```py
[array(['CA', '0'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['TEX', '1'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['FLO', '2'], dtype='<U21'),
 array(['ORE', '3'], dtype='<U21')]
```

```py
# Convert to a pandas data frame for plotting
P = pd.DataFrame(Z, columns=colNames) #save Z as a dataframe with columns colNames
P['prediction'] = P['prediction'].astype(int) #converting the values in Prediction column to int type
return P
```

here Z is converted to dataframe named P and the elements in the **prediction** column is converted to `int` type and P as the ultimate dataframe is returned. this prediction column is the cluster number.

if centers is a list of tuples, and it should be I assume, then instead of increasing indices, then the corresponding elements in each tuple are saved as A and index.

Comment: Is 'A' a placeholder? why they used A?

Comment: It is actually the elements of centers. if you set centers as ['CA', 'TEX', 'FLO', 'ORE'] , A refers to the elements of this list and index refers to indexes.